# 12v 25A power distribution PCB design

Tags: power-supply, high-current

The goal is to control 18 devices by using rocker switches with LED. The total ampere can be up to 25A.

The PCB size is 150mm x 250mm. The configuration is FR-4 with 2 oz/ft^2 copper. The bottom layer is GND plane where the top layer is 12V plane.

What are used:

1. 12v 350w power supply unit
2. Multiple 6P Barrier Terminal Blocks
3. 18 PTC resettable fuses
4. 18 12v-led-rocker switches

Is this setup safe for such current flow? Is there any potential hazard with this configuration? What can be done to improve the design?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It *seems* plausible, but I've never seen blade connector switches being directly soldered onto PCBs.

Comment: Have you calculated the required trace width for the currents you want to carry?

Comment: I used online tool to calculate the trace width. Seems 35mm trace is enough.

Answer (score 0):

as drawn the switches have a better connection to negative than they do to positive. 
especially the left column (the column closest to the switched terminals)

one way to fix:

On the right side use both planes to carry the negative supply.

commit most of the red side to distributing the positive supply.

on the purple side put the all traces that go to the switches traces and also the traces that grond the LEDs

Keep the PTCs on the red side, move them directly above the pin they feed and rotate them 90 degrees so that they impede less of the current that comes from the top of the board. - avoid making horizontal cuts in positive part the red plane.